# Google Analytics "daily Limit Exceeded Quota error" & register application properly with gapi.class.php

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, limit, google-analytics-api, google-apps

I used gapi.class.php and have another analytics-dash.php template which I'm calling as an include on a page template in WP. This shows a chart and stats of analytics on the front end of WP to my admin and authors. This template is connected to my site's GA profile ID and all is well, it works and shows the stats. However, the first night after implementation we received the error "GDatadailyLimitExceededQuota" on the site. I have since removed the include script from my page template so the error will not show.

These are the steps I took to try and fix the problem:

1. I researched into the error "dailyLimitExceededQuota", which I researched and Google's API states the following: 

   "If quota is exceeded, Google Analytics API returns an error for additional requests:

   - HTTP status code 403 Forbidden and a message indicating that the specific account has insufficient quota to proceed...
   - 50,000 requests per project per day
   - 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP.

   To get full quota, you must register your application in the Google Developers Console. When you register a new application, you are given a unique client ID to identify each application under that project."
  Then I realized I needed to register with Google's Developer Console as the quota limit is very low for testing without registering.
2. I registered the application and turned on the Analytics API in the console. I'm not sure what else I am to do after registering the application.
3. I followed the instructions to increase the quota ([Configuration and Reporting API Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas#additional_quota))
   by using this form:
   [Analytics API quota request](https://docs.google.com/a/digitalmediamanagement.com/forms/d/1TUPt4LGXbOAqkYe4hYj_s-KPyhUDuJXdTt1lLihNOeg/viewform)
4. I went through the steps on the form to make sure I am setting this up correctly. On that form, it states the following:
   "Quotas that CAN be increased:

   - Per project daily limit of 50,000 requests/day.
   - Per project daily limit of 500 uploads/day.

   Quotas that CANNOT be increased:

   - Per profile (user) limit of 10,000 requests/day [403 Error with Message about Profile limit: dailyLimitExceeded]
   - Per profile (user) limit of 10 concurrent requests per profile [403 Error: quotaExceeded]
   - Per IP limits of 10 queries/second (QPS) [403 Error: userRateLimitExceeded]"
     ... proceed to check that we "Verify that the quota you are asking for can be increased. See the list above."

   This is referring to the quotas that can and cannot be increased (above). Since we received error "dailyLimitExceed", and this is associated with "per profile (user) limit of 10,000 requests/day" - this is under the list that CANNOT be increased.
    However this was before registering the application with Google's Developer Console so I'm thinking now, since I registered it as an application/project, it can be considered to have a daily limit of 50,000 requests/day. Then if I enable it again on our website, I'm thinking the error would not show, however this I am unsure because I'm not sure if I setup the registration fully. Could it be that simple to register an application? 

   The next step on the form states: 
   "(4) Verify your API requests are properly registered with a Developers Console Project. Check the Reports Developers Console. If total requests in the traffic report is 0 then your API requests are not registered to your project ID and you are not currently getting your full quota."
   However, it is going to show 0 currently because I removed the include script from our website! So I'm thinking the only way to test against this (#4 on form) is to put the script back in. Then if the error shows, that could mean that either it is not communicating with the registered application I just created, or it simply exceeds the limit. Therefore I would need to fill out this form, which I did, to ask for a quote increase. 
   However, I'm hesitant to put the script back in to display the analytics chart until I hear back from Google (not sure how long it takes for them to respond to the increase quota request) because I don't want another dailyLimitExceeded error to be thrown and show on the front end.

Any thoughts? Thank you very much for your consideration in helping.